# Python: Get list of applications associated with file (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, open-with

Am making an application in Python and I need to provide "Open with" menu to user. Currently I am parsing `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cashe` and `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` but with very poor results. Nautilus has more entries in "Open with" menu.

Do you know a better way for getting list of applications associated with file?

Edit:

There is a simpler way using `gnomevfs` module.

```
mime_type = gnomevfs.get_mime_type(filename)
application_list = gnomevfs.mime_get_all_applications(mime_type)
```

In returned list you get application name, icon name, config file and many other stuff.

Comment: This question is essentially the inverse of this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205984/get-a-list-of-file-types-that-can-be-opened-with-a-specific-application/206027#206027

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a bit more elegant solution. In `gnomevfs` module there is function named `mime_get_all_applications` which returns proper list of associated applications.

More information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PythonRecipes/MIMETypes).

Edit:
Since the time this answer was written, GnomeVFS was marked as deprecated. GIO does provide this functionality now with methods like `app_info_get_all` and `app_info_get_for_type`.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME stores its application lists in those two files:

```
/etc/gnome/defaults.list
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

[(link to source)](http://blog.scaron.info/index.php/2010/10/edit-gnomes-open-with-application-list/)

Comment: Thanks. At this point I think my code is faulty somehow. Need to check on that as well.

Comment: Yes they are. GnomeVFS is outdated, GIO is the stuff to use.